# Is it acceptable to have a database for direct queries and a second database for SSAS if they use the same data?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, data-warehouse

I am working on a server that will be used by many, many users across a large corporation and I have two databases storing the same information in different ways.

Databases:

- DB1 = Simple relational for direct queries
- DB2 = Star schema with facts and dimensions for the cubes

End Users:

- Analysts - create reports(crystal)/query data directly (using db 1)
- Management - use analysis cubes to look at data (using db 2)

Both are created/updated daily through two steps:

1. The production source data is imported and transformed into understandable, "common sense" relational tables stored in DB1.
2. This step transforms the DB1 tables into fact/dimension tables and stores them in DB2.  The SSAS cubes are then created based on these tables and stored here.

**Question**

Based on that description, is this acceptable from a design standpoint? Would it be better to ditch the "simple" database and then use views to assemble the data in "simple tables" for analysts to query?

Comment: ".. *transformed into understandable, "common sense" relational tables*" To you, me and other DB practitioners maybe.  But almost everyone else seems to find the dimensional approach more understandable (that's one of it's big pluses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's never a good idea to have *just* the data warehouse (your "DB 2").  When you denormalize data into a data warehouse or cube for reporting, you are "throwing away" information.  Summarizing away details means that the detailed information is lost.

Let's say that you suffer damage or loss of your cube/data warehouse.  Or alternatively, let's say that new types of analysis are needed which require you to recalculate your cubes.  If you've thrown away your raw, detailed data then you won't be able to recreate your summarized data.

For this reason, and perhaps because some kinds of queries may require or be more efficient against your transactional details, it's a good idea to load your raw data into a relational data store and then build your summarized cubes/star schemas out of that.

Note that whenever you have two data stores, you have the potential for the results to get out of sync.  You need to have rules and processes in place to handle these situations.  One data store should always be the "book of record".  Typically this will be the most detailed information (your DB 1).  You also want to have detective controls in place that look for discrepancies and recalculate your summarized data whenever the two data stores become out of sync.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Joel.  It makes a lot of sense when you frame it like that and as I am obviously not experienced with this kind of work your suggestions are worth their weight in gold my friend.

Edit: Both the DB1 and DB2 are wiped and recreated daily.  The DB2 is created directly from the DB1 tables which are created based on the production tables.

Answer (score 2):

Your typical data mart will include a staging area (either a different schema or a different database) where the raw data is brought basically unaltered.  This is essentially what you have with your DB1. Then your data load process will transform it into your facts and dimensions.  This is your DB 2.

Star schemas are not just for cubes.  They are great for SQL queries as well. You shouldn't be worried about "throwing away information".  You only "lose" the data you don't include in your schema.  Star schemas are optimized for reading/querying rather than writing and updating.  Typically, your star schema is easier to understand for analysts.  Also, their queries will typically include fewer joins with a star schema. I would bet that queries (written efficiently) against the denormalized star schema would return the data the analysts need quicker than the query to get that information from the normalized database most of the time. You can perform a test to prove this out. If analysts' queries are pulling mostly summarized data with few details, you can make summarized views in your fact tables that are at a higher level of granularity if you feel they are too slow, or you can give them access to your cube.  If they pull a lot of details, the detailed fact tables at their original level of granularity should be fine.  You can also help query times by using indexes effectively and tuning for the most frequently run queries.

Comment: You are conflating my advice regarding summarization and denormalization.  First off, if you summarize without keeping what you call the staging area, then you _are_ "throwing away information".  Second, if you use non-summarized detailed data in a star schema, then you are working with denormalized data.  _If_ your data is read-only, then working with denormalized transactional data _may_ not come back to haunt you.  However, every decision to use denormalized data should be made deliberately and with a careful consideration of the risks and consequences.

Comment: I was pointing out that you are making an assumption that a star schema automatically meant they were losing data by summarizing.  Many, if not most, data marts/warehouses use denormalized data. Many, if not most, of those data marts contain detail data, not just summary data. He mentioned that this data is only updated once a day, so it _is_ read-only. This is a reporting system, not a transactional system. I do agree that you have to have a good schema design and understand the desired granularity of your facts and dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the additional response mmarie.  You are correct, this is purely a reporting system.  The "transactions" are recorded on production tables on another server.  Using SSIS, the production tables are imported and transformed into a much easier format for the analysts to understand (75% are not experienced with SQL).  Next, DB2 takes the tables from DB1 and breaks them up into fact/dimensions for the SSAS cube.  No one can query DB2.  Both DB1/DB2 are "recreated" daily with SSIS. No data from the previous day persists through the update process.